# how to get query string parameters from a string? LUA/nginx

Tags: nginx, lua, query-string

i am using lua module inside nginx for routing to a stored string.
The thing i want to do is to change the values of query string parameters from the stored string.
Is there any function which will give me table of query string parameters from a string?
And after changing the values, any function to change the values from the string.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [ngx.encode_args](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#ngx.encode_args) and [ngx.decode_args](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#ngx.decode_args) respectively.